# Is there a way to monitor network traffic from outside the Vnet in Azure?

Tags: azure, metrics

I can view the network traffic into an Azure VM, but I would like to view network traffic coming from communications outside the LAN. Is it possible to show this info in Azure?

IE I have this graph which shows **total network usage**, but I would like to exclude communication from within the same LAN. Is such a thing possible in Azure or would I have to do it from within the VM itself?
[image: azure metrics]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your scenario, you could choose [Azure Network watcher](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-monitoring-overview#network-resource-level-monitoring).

Network Watcher - Scenario-based monitoring is provided with the features in Network Watcher. This service includes packet capture, next hop, IP flow verify, security group view, NSG flow logs. Scenario level monitoring provides an end to end view of network resources in contrast to individual network resource monitoring.

Comment: Hi, does it work for you?

Comment: Hi,

I'm just about to try network watchers, will report back here when I do :)

Comment: Should I be using `packet capture` to achieve total upload/download amount? Or is it some other tool within network watcher?

Comment: I think you could try. Based on my knowledge, Azure does not provide other same tool.